# Mount bluetooth FTP as filesystem in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, bluetooth

Is it possible to mount a bluetooth "filesystem" (a bluetooth device that offers the [Bluetooth FT profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profiles#File_Transfer_Profile_.28FTP.29)) as a network share on a Windows 7 system?

I want to be able to open a file from my phone directly via Bluetooth with a path like `Q:\file-to-open`.